# Element positioning on android Layout grid-based

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I've drawn a background (using photoshop) with a circle forming a 4x4 grid. I would like to position some element (like a little circle image/button) inside the circle accurately. How can I do this? Should I use a particular layout? It's a background for a grid-based game.
Background (It will be more accurate): http://uptiki.altervista.org/viewer.php?file=spojjb30484tjasmqbo2.png

Comment: Pictures would definitely help here.

Comment: I can't post image because of my rep :(

Comment: @Ste_ you could still link to an external images site

Comment: Image added on question!

Answer (score 0):

You should split the background into 2 parts. 
1. A background with whatever fancy image it has to the gridview. 
2. Indiviudual cells in the gridview has it's own background that can be circle or square or different colored circles to show selected cell, etc.